# Default Test Database When MySQL is Installed and Started

Tags: mysql

In most versions of MySQL that I've worked with, there is a default "test" database that is pre-loaded with the performance, information, and mysql databases.  I've never seen this database populated.  Is it safe to delete this DB or will MySQL use this as a resource in the future?

Comment: Something is called `test`? Shoot first and ask questions later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [mySQL manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/database-use.html) says:

> The `test` database often is available as a workspace for users to try things out.

that's arguably good enough reason to assume it's safe to remove.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can delete it... but the fact that you are asking indicates that the installations in question may not have been properly secured and may still also have the anonymous accounts active also. There is an official script to take care of both:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mysql-secure-installation.html